# Aligning responsive "notice board" to the left and a larger "framed main text" area directly to the right

Tags: html, css, alignment, responsive

I'm developing my first full website and I'm having an issue aligning a "notice board" (used for urgent notices) and the "main frame" (used for general messages on page). I've already got my hero banner and navigation bar to be responsive and generally worked out, but I can't get the "notice board" & "main frame" worked out properly to align like the attached image and remain responsive.

example of page layout I'm looking for

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try using a grid?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout
If you had two divs you could tell it to use the following css on the container div:

```
display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
```

And it should align perfectly to how your picture looks.

If you want an older way of doing it: check out flexbox. This would need a flex display on the outer container, then you can set values for how much each div inside it would take and how to wrap items, ect.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

If you need an even older way of doing it, just take the notices and float that div to the left.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-float-and-columns-to-lay-out-content-with-css

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice man! I'll get right on giving those a go. I appreciate cha!

Comment: Anytime, let me know if you have other questions. If it works out for you, please accept, I need the reputation to make other comments.

Comment: I accepted! I'm learning more about this new css grid system, and I'm having a bit of trouble sizing things right and making them properly responsive, but I really do think this will be the answer to my problem once I work out the kinks! Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the accepted post. I would also HIGHLY recommend Kevin Powell on Youtube, he is outstanding, this will teach you about grid and css
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU tons of free videos to get you feeling like an expert.

Comment: @Xootie - just making sure you saw the link I left yesterday

Comment: Just seeing now thanks man I'll check him out!